# halt-resume execution of user-supplied javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, interpreter, resume

I've searched the web all around but maybe I'm just asking a wrong thing and Google returns me wrong answers :)

I have an AJAX-based tool that is used to test an API suit (it's not one of the many available tools like soapUI, though somewhat similar in purpose). It has many "pre-packaged" API templates that a developer can play with while writing the back-end code.

So far so good and I could go with either a blocking or non-blocking AJAX calls in this interactive mode, when a user selects the API to test, if necessary modifies the text of the request and fires up the API - once it's done a result is displayed. Again, this part can be done either synchronously or asynchronously quite easily.

Once I was done with this basic functionality it occurred to me that it's quite simple to `eval()` user-supplied code that could do more than just a single API request, effectively building a tool that can do flow-testing (so one can write a few lines of "code" to login, get user details, and then perform some other APIs).

There's a simple API-calling function defined by my tool which basically accepts one parameter - the name of an API to be called (the rest of data comes from various form data). Quite obviously there's little restriction on what user's JS code can do - it can call APIs in a loop, for example.

This is where I'm hitting a roadblock. I'm currently forced to run my API requests via a blocking AJAX call, because I have to halt the user's script execution until that API is completed. The nature of the APIs is such that it's often required for the previous API to return result(s) before the next API can be run (an example would be a "get user details" that has to wait for a "login" API call to complete).

With the non-blocking AJAX I've tried to "cut" the code and execute "the rest of it" once the callback function was called, but it's easy to see how this doesn't work very well in general case - when the "cut" happens to be inside a code block, like an `if-else` or a loop.

Trying to manually parse and execute JS quite rapidly becomes a generic problem of creating my own VM, which is definitely outside of the amount of effort I'm willing to spend on this (unless I decide it's worth a year of two of undivided attention, but for that I'd probably need to win a lottery).

My question is - is there a (preferably elegant?) way to halt the script's execution while allowing the user to supply a "simple" linear code that runs as if it was a single-threaded execution?

Comment: How about you make a worker function, which collates all the requests, and executes the ones that are "chained" i.e. has a callback in a blocking call, and executes the one which does not have such dependencies asynchronously?

Comment: I would seriously consider using jQuery. You'll get some nice tools to play with AJAX and callbacks like [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: I am using jQuery, but it doesn't have a "halt-resume arbitrary JS code" functionality

Comment: @Raidenace user's code is meant to process data in-between those calls, so I can't simply queue them up - they have to be called "in the flow" of the user's code

Comment: @YePhIcK guess I am having a bit of difficulty fully comprehending your particular use case. Suppose there is a chained flow, like `call A->call B->call C`. Are you saying that user needs to halt the flow at, say, `call B`, examine the data and resume `call C`?

Comment: no, "I" need to interrupt the flow and do some processing of the returned data to make it available for the next call. Thus I need to execute the user-provided JS that includes calls to my function but if I'm to call AJAX asynchronously I need to pause that user's code execution until after the API is completed